# Object required Error: if range.value = "x"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a cell value obtained from a range in an if statement, but I am getting this error.

```
Run-time error '424':
Object required
```

This is what my code is trying to do.

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find("hello").offset(1, 0)

test123 = False
While test123 = False
    If rng.Value = ""           <- error line
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        test123 = True
    End If
Wend
```

Any help would be awesome, thanks!

Edit: My data looks something like this. I am trying to delete all blank rows between "hello" and the next non-blank row. So my code is searching for hello and then offsetting the row by 1. The if is used to test whether the next row is blank, which will keep repeating til the next row is not blank

```
table 1

Row Header:
bye
hi
hello


thank you
```

Comment: It means that `hello` was not found in the range.

Comment: is there a way to write the if statement if rng points to a blank cell?

Comment: `If Not rng is nothing then`

Comment: i just tried it but it is never evaluating to False even when rng points to a blank cell

Comment: If hello was not found, then `rng` is `Nothing`, not a blank cell.

Comment: sorry i think i  did a bad job replicating the problem. see edits

Comment: please add the code that iterates the blanks.

Comment: added. im assuming that when you delete a row, everything shifts up so the row of the previously blank column that was just deleted would now be the next row, but I am not sure if that is how it actually works

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when you delete the first row `rng` is deleted and will error if referred to again.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").Find("hello")
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim rw As Long
rw = rng.Row + 1

Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, 2) = ""
    Rows(rw).Delete
Loop
```